# Using Automapper for Many-To-Many Relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I'm trying to use Automapper for a many-to-many relationship and entity framework.

This is my entity:

```
public class ZChangeUnits
{
    [Key]
    public string CCode1 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CCode1")]
    public virtual ZUnits ZUnits1 { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string CCode2 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CCode2")]
    public virtual ZUnits ZUnits2 { get; set; }

    public decimal NZarib { get; set; }
}
```

And this is `ZUnit` entity:

```
[Key]
public string CCode { get; set; }

public string CTitle { get; set; }

public string CMGCode { get; set; }
public virtual ZCodes ZCodes { get; set; }
```

I want to map them to this ViewModel, probably I should remove Titles:

```
public class ChangeUnitsViewModel
{
    public string CCode1 { get; set; }
    public string ZUnitsCTitle1 { get; set; }
    public string CCode2 { get; set; }
    public string ZUnitsCTitle2 { get; set; }
    public decimal NZarib { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the mapping I'm currently using:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ZChangeUnits, ChangeUnitsViewModel>()
    .ForMember(d => d.ZUnitsCTitle1,
        o => o.MapFrom(s => s.ZUnits1.CTitle))
    .ForMember(d => d.ZUnitsCTitle2,
        o => o.MapFrom(s => s.ZUnits2.CTitle));
```

But it doesn't seem valid and gives the `Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.` exception.

Can you please guide me about how I can use Automapper to perform a basic CRUD operation on this class? Any useful link, I have no idea how to use it.

To make this really complete, this is my controller!

```
var data = exchangeRepo.GetAll().ToList();
var d = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ChangeUnitsViewModel>(data);
```